# Fire conversion pixel when iframe loads thank you page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a question regarding my current website. On my website I have an iframe containing a flights booking form. They don't allow me to implement a tracking pixel on their end when a user lands on the thank you page (booking confirmation). I need this tracking to do my media buying properly, otherwise I won't know if the media I'm buying is actually converting.

Inside the iframe I can detect the following pages being loaded as I go along the booking steps:

domain.../itinerary/review

domain.../itinerary/traveller

domain.../itinerary/product

domain.../itinerary/pay

domain.../itinerary/confirm (booking is paid and confirmed)

When the last page is loaded inside the iframe, I would like to fire a tracking pixel. This will be an image or custom html pixel, sample below:

```
<img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"     src="https://www.facebook.com/tr/?    ev=1234567890&cd[value]=10.00&cd[currency]=USD&noscript=1" />
```

If the pixel in this case can be a google tag manager code, that would be even better. Below a sample of the google tag manager code:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ABCDE"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MBKH6F');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

If anybody here can help even a little, I would be incredibly grateful.

Thanks,

Joost

Comment: Maybe you sort of indirectly answered this already, but is it possible for you to ask the vendor to place your GTM container on the thank you page?

Comment: hi there nyuen, no unfortunately they don't allow this:
"They don't allow me to implement a tracking pixel on their end when a user lands on the thank you page (booking confirmation)."